# *maps.API без SSL

Tags: геолокация

Нужнен рецепт простой карты для веб-страницы, которая будет работать везде и всегда, с любым клиентом - планшет, смартфон, декстоп. И в подавляющем большинстве браузеров, если они вообще способны открыть *карту. Сайт, на котором это будет болтаться, не имеет сертификата SSL.

Клиенту показывается карта (гугл или яндекс), по возможности (если есть у браузера есть geolocation) уже установленная на его, клиента, нынешнее местоположение.

По клику на карте ставится метка, а координаты метки пишутся в input формы на той же странице. Что-то типа document.getElementById('startLat').value = position.coords.latitude. Повторный клик по другому месту на карте переставляет метку туда, старая метка пропадает, координаты в input-е обновляются. Больше ничего не требуется.

Я пытался сделать через navigator.geolocation, но работает нестабильно - с декстопа работает, с андроида даже не запрашивает разрешение получить location, сразу permission denied, хотя там всё разрешено.

Comment: Покажите ваш код.